# Powershell to set default browser

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, browser, powershell, powershell-3.0

I created a process using PowerShell to install Chrome.  What I am looking to do now is to have PowerShell change the registry for the computer and change the default browser to Chrome.

I would want this done for all users and not just the current user.
Right now I have this

```
Set-Itemproperty -path HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice -name "ProgId" -value ChromeHTML -force 
Set-Itemproperty -path HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice -name "ProgId" -value ChromeHTML -force
```

to set the browser to default, but it is not working.

Comment: All relevant information should be in the question body instead of a comment.

Comment: How are you running this for the other users?

Comment: Hi! I've tried using the code form this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536405/cant-set-chrome-as-default-browser-from-powershell/54735265#54735265) and making my own version of the code. But it doesn't really work more than once (or once for that matter) because Windows 10 creates a unique hash every time you set a browser as default. Even being the same browser seconds after the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you would need to create the equivalent in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations

Comment: Yes you're in good direction. Explain your answer with more details, like how one can do that? What steps do they need? What do the commands do? Some example. etc.